# Qt thread problem with single core CPU on Windows XP

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, qt, qthread

I am developing a cross-platform fractal explorer using Qt. I am experiencing a performance problem specifically when running on a single core CPU under Windows XP (program compiled with MSVC Express 2010), I haven't tried other versions of Windows. With two cores the program runs fine. It also runs fine under Linux with either one core or two cores (compiled with GCC).

The performance problem is something to do with calling a slot in the widget via the signal in the calculation thread. The widget contains a QImage and I pass a pointer to its pixels to the calculation thread. The thread calculates the fractal and plots the pixels to the image. At the end of each row, the thread emits a signal to the widget to tell it to update the display in the main thread. As I understand it, this is a queued connection.

With Windows and a single CPU the update is very slow, much slower than the calculation. It makes the program unusable.

The relevant code is similar to the Mandelbrot example in the Qt docs, except my signal has no arguments because the Qimage is located in the widget not the thread and I do not convert the QImage to a QPixmap.

Does anybody have any ideas of what the problem could be and how to go about solving it? Is it something to do with scheduling, time slicing allocation? Is there a compiler flag in MSVC that I need to set? Or do I need to modify my program some how?

Thanks very much!

Comment: You say the code is similar to the Mandelbrot example - does the Mandelbrot example also exhibit exhibit the problem? In other words, is the problem likely to be due to the differences you list, or not?

Comment: That's a good idea, I will have to try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the update is slower than the calculation - how much slower? Have you done any comprehensive profiling to see where exactly the bottleneck occurs? A cursory google finds [this profiler](http://smartbear.com/products/development-tools/performance-profiling/) which may help you.

Remember that for older CPU's, thread context switching is very expensive. This may be part of your problem, though again I don't know specifics.

Comment: No I haven't done any profiling, thanks for the suggestion. If I disable the by-row update and only update at the end of the calculation then it takes just a couple of seconds to complete. With the update it takes many more seconds. I will have to time it be more precise.

Comment: I experimented with emitting the update signal only every 20ms or every row, whichever comes last. This greatly improved the performance, so it looks like context switching is the culprit. I will have to redesign some of the code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is context switching expensive for the Pentium M 1.8 Ghz?If I enable colour scrolling at the same time as the calculation then the calculation virtually stops.

Comment: Something similar happens with Fraqtive (also written in Qt), but not with Ultra Fractal (a commercial fractal program, not written in Qt). So the problem could be with how Qt handles context switching on Windows?

Comment: Why do you need to write this code on such an antiquated computer? Even if you work out specific errors, you will be much better served overall by using a modern system with at least 2 cores.

Comment: I didn't, I'm just testing on an antiquated computer :) My development machine is a 3Ghz Core2 Duo. The colour scrolling would take up a lot of cpu time and the gui thread is a higher priority than the computation thread, so that would explain the bad performance (even without context switching). I should be okay now to fix it. Thanks again!